# i can't connect to my elastic search in google cloud platform

Tags: angular, firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I am using angular 5 in my project and I have already setup my elasticsearch and kibana in gcp. Everything works fine until I tried to connect it to my project. I know I have to send my credentials, but it did not work and I tried also to add some CORS in the elasticsearch.yml, but no progress at all. For my database is firebase and use it service to create my elastic search instance.  I want to connect it to my project can anyone help me with this? thank you

Here's my code :

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({

       host: 'http://user:pass@35.225.247.57//elasticsearch',

      log: 'trace',
     });
     client.ping({
      // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout

    }, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.trace(error);
      } else {
        console.log('All is well');
      }
    });
```

This is the response of the server

```
Failed to load http://35.225.247.57//elasticsearch/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I added some CORS to elasticsearch.yml

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"
```

Comment: As I understand from your question, you have an angular 5 application that you want to connect to a elasticsearch + kibana that you've setup in a GCE (Google Compute Engine) VM instance.
You want to connect the application to the instance running elasticsearch+kibana, therefore you need authentication.
I don't understand what you mean when you say that you create the elasticseach GCE instance with the firebase database service.
Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: - Is the angular application running inside your GCP (Google Cloud Platform) project?
- The firebase database is running jointly with the angular application?
- If the firebase database inside the GCP project?

Comment: If all of the resources that you've described are running inside your GCP project then you need to make use of a service account for authentication as decribed here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/repository-gcs-usage.html

WARNING: the link above is preliminary documentation for a elastic future release, I linked it because it explains how authentication works on GCP.

Comment: If all of your resources are within a GCP project then there is no need for an external IP address.

As you've mentioned you are using CORS, I'm linking here a related StackOVerflow thread with a helpful answer marked as accepted:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

The above thread mentions this CORS setup guide that you can check:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `http.cors.enabled` setting is also set to `true`

Configure the `http.cors.allow-origin` with a sensible value (`*` is ok for testing but you should not go to production with that; limit it to the origin you will be using)

Then, you have to restart the ElasticSearch service after you make changes to the configuration.

```
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

For what it's worth, you should also disable the plain-text HTTP access and switch over to HTTPS exclusively. Especially since you are passing the credentials in clear text..

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes im using just a simple plain text for testing i was trying to secure it but i encountered this problem, i have tried your solution above but it didn't work same issue it seems @Mike Dinescu